# Create a button in an Angular directive that will remove the entire directive

Tags: angularjs

Let's say I have a "filterList" element. Inside is a list of `<filter-item>` angular directives. I want each `<filter-item>` to have a "delete" button inside of it. Clicking the delete button will remove the `<filter-item>` from the DOM.

How can I do this?

```
<div class="filterList">
   <filter-item></filter-item>
   <filter-item></filter-item>
   <filter-item></filter-item>
</div>
```

FilterItem directive:

```
myApp.directive('filterItem', ['$http', function($http){
  return {
    scope: { },
    replace: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      scope.remove = function() {
        // Hmm, I sure do wonder what goes here Mr Jones.
      }
    },
    template: '<div>Hi mom! <button on-click="remove()">Remove</button></div>'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of `link` you can do `element.remove();`.

Since AngularJS has jqLite, `remove()` removes the directive's element from the DOM. If your directive is *not* tied to any model, this is acceptable.  Be careful manipulating the DOM like this when directives are rendered as a result of the model, since you haven't changed the model you can end up with strange effects (e.g. re-rendering).

(Self-answer but found a good post not on StackOverflow)

```
myApp.directive('filterItem', ['$http', function($http){
  return {
    scope: { },
    replace: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      scope.remove = function() {
        element.remove();
      }
    },
    template: '<div>Hi mom! <button on-click="remove()">Remove</button></div>'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

method 1: i dont know if this is the right way to do it but you can use

```
<div class="filterList">
   <filter-item></filter-item>
   <filter-item></filter-item>
   <filter-item></filter-item>
</div>
FilterItem directive:

myApp.directive('filterItem', ['$http', function($http){
  return {
    scope: {
       hideDir:'=?'
    },
    replace: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      scope.remove = function() {
        // Hmm, I sure do wonder what goes here Mr Jones.
         element.innerHTML='';
      }
    },
    template: '<div>Hi mom! <button on-click="remove()">Remove</button></div>'
  }
});
```

method 2: you can also try using ng-if and change variable inside directive

```
<div class="filterList" ng-if="!hideDir" hide-dir="hideDir">
   <filter-item></filter-item>
   <filter-item></filter-item>
   <filter-item></filter-item>
</div>
FilterItem directive:

myApp.directive('filterItem', ['$http', function($http){
  return {
    scope: {
       hideDir:'=?'
    },
    replace: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      scope.remove = function() {
        // Hmm, I sure do wonder what goes here Mr Jones.
        scope.hideDir=true;
      }
    },
    template: '<div>Hi mom! <button on-click="remove()">Remove</button></div>'
  }
});
```

Comment: You don't seem to use `element.innerHTML = '';` anywhere in your example

Comment: they are 2 different approaches can follow. not the same code